# How to mark a point on a graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics

So I'm obtaining the following graph:

```
graphicDelayZOOM = 
 LogLinearPlot[GroupDelay /. w -> 2 \[Pi] f, {f, 10, 3000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{100, 3000}, {0.000116, 0.0001201}}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, 
  PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[1.5], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"f(Hz)", "time"}, 
  Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image]

Now I want to display the point f1=2000, GroupDelay(f1). Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Use the option `Epilog -> {Pointsize[Medium], Black, Point[{ f, GroupDelay /. w-> 2 Pi f} /. f->2000] }`

Comment: @LouisB thank you, am I supposed to write that after BaseStyle? I get an error.

Comment: @LouisB I got it, it was Pointsize that should PointSize. However, the point is not displaying, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, `PointSize`.  My bad.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @LouisB the point is not displaying though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Mesh + MeshStyle

You can use the options `Mesh` and `MeshStyle`:

```
GroupDelay = 0.00012 Erfc[w/10000/Pi];

LogLinearPlot[GroupDelay /. w -> 2 π f, {f, 10, 3000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 3000}, All},
 Mesh -> {{2000}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

#### Epilog

To use `Epilog` we need to log-transform the horizontal coordinate of the point we wish to add:

```
LogLinearPlot[GroupDelay /. w -> 2 π f, {f, 10, 3000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 3000}, All}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{Log@2000, GroupDelay /. w -> 2 π 2000}]}]
```

[image]

#### ListLogLinearPlot + Show

```
Show[LogLinearPlot[GroupDelay /. w -> 2 π f, {f, 10, 3000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{10, 3000}, All}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[{{2000, GroupDelay /. w -> 2 π 2000}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]